# Why is $\mathbb{R}^3$ not the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space defined by kernel $k(x,y)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let the input space be $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}^2$, and kernel function $k(x,y)=\langle x,y \rangle^2 = (x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$.

I can write

\begin{align}
k(x,y) &= x_1^2 y_1^2 + x_2^2 y_2^2 + 2 x_1 y_1 x_2 y_2 \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & \sqrt{2}x_1 x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1^2 \\ y_2^2 \\ \sqrt{2}y_1 y_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}

The feature map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is then $\phi(x)=k_x=k(\cdot, x) = (x_1^2, x_2^2, \sqrt{2}x_1 x_2)$. Since $\phi: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{H}$ maps input vector to the RKHS defined by $k$, I conclude that $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}^3$.

But page 41 of [this lecture presentation](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/coursefiles/RKHS2013_slides1.pdf)  says otherwise, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not the RKHS defined by kernel $k(x,y)=(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)^2$. If not, then what is the RKHS defined by kernel $k$?

Answer (score -1):

The RKHS defined by that kernel is not the "whole" $\mathbb{R}^3$, but a two dimensional manifold defined in it. Note that, for instance, the vector $(1,1,1)$ is not in the image of $\phi(x)$.

Comment: My impression is that $\mathcal{H}$ is not defined by $\{\phi(x) | x \in \mathcal{X} \}$, but all functions of the form $f(x)=ax_1^2+bx_2^2+cx_1x_2$ (hence $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{R}^3$) . See [these slides](https://dependence2013.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/columbia14_lecture1.pdf), p.36-37

Comment: The kernel which is reproducing on some Hilbert space does map into a manifold within that space, but is a reproducing kernel on the entire space. Remember that the space is defined as the *completion* of the space spanned by $K(., x)_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}$ (c.f. Moore-Aronszajn Theorem).

Comment: On the other hand, I'm still trying to get my head around which space is the unique RKHS associated with a given kernel, given that one could similarly construct a mapping into $\mathbb{R}^4$, or indeed an alternative mapping into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (see the 1998 tutorial on support vector machines by Burgess).  I have a running theory that the mapping is in fact into $l^2({\mathbb{R^2}})$, and we treat any finite-dimensional Euclidian space as a Hilbert subspace (this doesn't then violate uniqueness of the RKHS space) but I'm still trying to understand it. Thoughts welcome!